# Generate sample data according to a suposed proportion

Tags: python, r, excel, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I am working on a project where products in production have a defect, but in very rare cases. For example 1/1,000,000 products have a defect.

How could I generate data, in R, Python, or Excel, that would represent samples from this distribution ?

Comment: Just use R's `sample` function and specify this proportion as your probabilities. And then sample as many elemnts as you want. Of course, you'd probably need to draw a few million elements in your case before you actually get one defunct one in your sampled data.

Answer (score 1):

In R you could do: `sample(c(1, rep(0, (1e6)-1)), size = 10)`

You can adjust the sizing parameter accordingly. With `size=10` you'll get 10 samples: `[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

It'll take a while before you see a `1` with this probability of `1/1e6`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll than try to see if I can find another bootstraping method in order to work with less data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `tidyverse` in `R` you can do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
tibble(
  group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  id = seq_len(5)
) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  add_count(name = "group_size") %>%
  slice_sample(n = min(.$group_size)) %>% 
  select(-group_size)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group    id
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     2     5
#> 4     2     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You use the size of the smaller group as `n` and draw a sample from the other group with the same size. Instead of `min(.$group_size)` you can also set number, if you prefer.